# Jquery Datepicker element displaying date in incorrect format and messed up styling

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having a problem with my datepicker element that is driving me crazy. I am using the following code to create the datepicker element in index.cshtml:

```
@using ChartDataStructures;
@model UpToDate
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new {
    @class = "datePicker",
    @Value = Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    })
}

@section DatePicker{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var dateString = "@Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
            var defaultDate = new Date(dateString);
            $(".datePicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                defaultDate: defaultDate
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

And here is my UpToDate model:

```
namespace ChartJSCore.Demo.Models
{
    public class UpToDate
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am importing the relevant jQuery scripts in my layout.cshtml file like this:

```
Copy code
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ChartJSCore.Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/ChartJSCore.Demo.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Head", required: false)
</head>
@RenderSection("DatePicker", required: true)
```

The problem is that the date is displaying in the wrong format, but it displays correctly when changing the date. Additionally, the styling of the datepicker is messed up.

[image: Wrong initial date format and incorrect styling]
[image: correct date format after choosing a date from the date picker]

I have been trying to fix this for hours and I can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using the [`dateFormat`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option?

Comment: I think you should using [`setDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method.

Comment: See my answer. tell me if there was a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@section DatePicker{
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       var dateString = "@Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
       var defaultDate = new Date(dateString);

       $(".datepicker").datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
       });
       $(".datepicker").datepicker( "setDate", defaultDate );

   });
</script>
}
```

if this answer is not correct, you sholde change `var dateString = "2023-01-22";` and try this.  (*2023-01-22 is example.*)
If the problem is solved, the problem is from this line.

and for using default template: use

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

You cleared the `rel="stylesheet"` in your code.

sorry for my english if it's bad